# R apply function - Getting error "Error during wrapup: wrong sign in 'by' argument"

Tags: r, date

I am trying to find the number of working days between two dates in R. I am using the following code

```
test_weekday <- function(a,b) sum(!weekdays(seq(as.Date(a), as.Date(b), "days")) %in% c("Saturday", "Sunday"))-1
apply(b1[,c(48,51)], 1, function(x) test_weekday(x[1],x[2]))
```

Getting the error -

> Error during wrapup: wrong sign in 'by' argument

Trace back shows this -

> 8 seq.Date(as.Date(a), as.Date(b), "days") 
> 7 seq(as.Date(a),
>   as.Date(b), "days")  
> 6 weekdays(seq(as.Date(a), as.Date(b),
>   "days"))  
> 5 match(x, table, nomatch = 0L)  
> 4
>   weekdays(seq(as.Date(a), as.Date(b), "days")) %in% c("Saturday", 
>       "Sunday")  
> 3 test_weekday(x[1], x[2])  
> 2 FUN(newX[, i], ...)  
> 1 apply(b1[, c(48, 51)], 1, function(x) test_weekday(x[1],
>   x[2]))

Please help

Also let me know if there is a better way of doing this. Thanks!

Comment: could you include a sample of your data

Comment: Try specifying the format that your dates are in when you call `as.Date` using `%d` `%m` and `%Y` to denote respectively day month and year. For example as in `as.Date(..,format="%m-%d-%Y")` if you format is month-day-year.